# A question about solvable finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the finite residually solvable group is solvable ?
please could you explain  why ?

thank you very much.

Comment: G is residually solvable means :  for every g in G (g different to e ), there is a normal subgroup N of G such that g is not in N and G/N is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, residually solvable is equivalent to solvable in the finite case. Another characterization of a residually solvable group is, that the derived series of the group reaches the identity element in countably many steps - see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Residually_solvable_group). Now if the group is finite, then it reaches the identity in finitely many steps. Hence it is solvable.

Comment: can you please explain to me more how the derived series of the group reaches the identity . Thank you

Comment: If $G$ is finite, and $G\neq [G,G]$, then $[G,G]$ has less elements. After finitely many steps then $G^ {(n)}=1$. If $G=[G,G]$, then $G$ is not residually solvable. Same, if some of the derived subgroups stabilize.