# Residually solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to answer the following problem:

> A group $G$ is said to be residually solvable if for every $g\in G \backslash \left\{e\right\}$ there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $g\notin N$ and $G/N$ is solvable.
>
> Show that a finite residually solvable group is solvable.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475266/a-question-about-solvable-finite-group/2475322#2475322).

Comment: i didn't understand the answer there could you please detail it more? thanks

Comment: "reaches the identity in countably many steps", for finite $G$ just means "reaches the identity in finitely many steps". But this is the definition of $G$ solvable.